# SOLVING INTEGRO-DIFFERENTIAL EQU

Tags: equation-solving

KINDLY SOMEONE SOLVE THIS EQU I M UNABLE TO SOLVE SECOND PART WHICH HAVE INTEGRAL TERM

```
A = to^(2)*(Io/a)^(fm)*(fc)^2*mue*Log[c];
B = zo^2*fm*4*(\[Pi])^(2)*row*(c^(2) - 1);
M = A/B;
beta = (fc*mue*Log[c]*zo)/(2*\[Pi]);
Zimp = (Lo/Co)^(0.5);
sigma = rcir/Zimp;



     NDSolve [{y''[x] == (M*g[x]^(2) - y'[x]^2)/y[x], 
          g'[x] == (1 - NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 3}] - 
              beta*g[x]*y'[x] - (sigma*g[x]))/(1 + beta*y[x]), 
          y[0] == 0.00001, y'[0] == 0, g[0] == 0, {g, y}, {x, 0, 3}}]

        Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], g[x]}/.192], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

Comment: No need to shout :)

Comment: `NDSolve` requires numerical values. What are `to, Io, a, fm` etc.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: Why close?  This question is of interest for everyone, who has a differential equation with definite integral of the function of interest in it. The answer shows, you often can get a solution by iterative evaluation.

Comment: I HV ALL NUMERIAL VALUES

Comment: I HV SOLVED THIS ISSUE OF INTEGRAL BY TAKING DIFFERENTIAL ON BOTH SIDES

Answer (score 6):

Since g[x] should be known th calculate the integral, you can start with a guess for the integral, get a g[x], recalculate the integral and start with this new value and hope it converges after serveral steps.

And indeed it does converge.

```
to = 6.48*10^-7; zo = 5; Io = 
4.97*10^(14)*3; a = 1.9; fm = 0.1; fc = 0.7; mue = 
10^(7)/4 Pi; c = 2.2; Lo = 15*10^-9; Co = 28*10^-6; rcir = 
2.5*10^-3; row = 3.15*10^(-3); A = 
to^(2)*(Io/a)^(fm)*(fc)^2*mue Log[c]; B = 
zo^2*fm*4*(Pi)^(2)*row*(c^(2) - 1); M = 
A/B; beta = (fc mue*Log[c]*zo)/(2*Pi); Zimp = (Lo/Co)^(0.5); sigma = 
rcir/Zimp

A = to^(2)*(Io/a)^(fm)*(fc)^2*mue*Log[c];
B = zo^2*fm*4*(\[Pi])^(2)*row*(c^(2) - 1);
M = A/B;
beta = (fc*mue*Log[c]*zo)/(2*\[Pi]);
Zimp = (Lo/Co)^(0.5);
sigma = rcir/Zimp;

int := NIntegrate[g[x] /. First@ndsol, {x, 0, 3}]
```

Start with int2=1/10 and print the difference of the integrals of two subsequent steps and print the new int.

```
int2 = 1/10; {ndsol = 
  NDSolve[Rationalize[{y''[x] == (M*g[x]^(2) - y'[x]^2)/y[x], 
  g'[x] == (1 - int2 - beta*g[x]*y'[x] - (sigma*g[x]))/(1 + 
      beta*y[x]), y[0] == 0.00001, y'[0] == 0, g[0] == 0}, 0], {g,
  y}, {x, 0, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];, int - int2, int2 = int}

(*   {Null, -0.0799695, 0.0200305}   *)
```

Iterate (here 10 times) until difference is very small

```
Table[{ndsol = 
   NDSolve[Rationalize[{y''[x] == (M*g[x]^(2) - y'[x]^2)/y[x], 
   g'[x] == (1 - int2 - beta*g[x]*y'[x] - (sigma*g[x]))/(1 + 
       beta*y[x]), y[0] == 0.00001, y'[0] == 0, g[0] == 0}, 
  0], {g, y}, {x, 0, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];, int - int2, 
  int2 = int}, {10}]

(*   {{Null, 0.000876807, 0.0209073}, {Null, -9.41326*10^-6, 
    0.0208979}, {Null, 1.01082*10^-7, 0.020898}, {Null, -1.08544*10^-9, 
    0.020898}, {Null, 1.16561*10^-11, 0.020898}, {Null,   -1.23374*10^-13,
    0.020898}, {Null, -2.33147*10^-15, 0.020898}, {Null, 
   1.26982*10^-15, 0.020898}, {Null, -1.34615*10^-15, 0.020898}, {Null,
   1.34615*10^-15, 0.020898}}   *)
```

Test how good difference of both sides of equations yield zero

```
Plot[y''[x] - ((M*g[x]^(2) - y'[x]^2)/y[x]) /. ndsol, {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[g'[x] - ((1 - int2 - beta*g[x]*y'[x] - (sigma*g[x]))/(1 + 
   beta*y[x])) /. ndsol, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Since error is very small, show g[x] and y[x]

```
Plot[g[x] /. ndsol, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y[x] /. ndsol, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]